# Wrong insert and select with self relationship many-to-many

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-annotations, discriminator, self-reference

I have a abstract superclass "view"

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="tipo", length=1)
public abstract class View extends DefaultModel implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4850147998379161237L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    ...

    public abstract List<Institution> getInstitutions();
}
```

a children institution class

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Institution extends View implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -18542249993446160L;

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Institution> getInstitutions() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(this);
    }

}
```

and a children group

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class GroupInstitution extends View {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6552513217676651258L;

    @ManyToMany
    List<Institution> institutions = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Institution> getInstitutions() {
        return institutions;
    }
}
```

I saved 3 institutions. Ok.
I tried to save a group with these three institutions. This created a new view (type = 2). But the relationship table looked like this:

```
2, 1
2, 2
2, 3
```

ie DiscriminatorValue used in place of GroupInstitution.id (I changed the DiscriminatorValue to 3, just testing, and the relationship was done with the 3)

Annotation is a mistake?